# Linked List delete function issue in C

Tags: c, linked-list

So I have a linkedlist and I am trying to delete the name of the input, but the delete function cannot find the name on the list. I am trying to find the logic flaw, I need some help!

some knowledge to know:
name is a character array in the struct

```
 case 4:
                     if(head == NULL)
                        printf("List is Empty\n");
                    else
                    {
                        printf("Enter the name to delete : ");
                        scanf("%s",&user);

                        if(delete(user))
                            printf("%s deleted successfully\n",user);
                        else
                            printf("%s not found in the list\n",user);
                    }
                    break;




int delete(const char* input)
{
    struct person *temp, *prev;
    temp = head;

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
         if(temp->name == input)
        {
            if(temp == head)
            {
                head = temp->next;
                free(temp);
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                prev->next = temp->next;
                free(temp);
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here? temp->name == input You are comparing pointer.

Comment: Read this: ["How do I check if a value matches a string?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598425/how-do-i-check-if-a-value-matches-a-string) And fwiw, this can be [considerably shortened](http://pastebin.com/5YTxYDL0).

Answer (score 1):

`if(temp->name == input)` is just comparing pointers. Try `if (strcmp(temp->name, input) == 0)`...

Comment: Thanks. What does strcmp do that changes the linked list

Comment: strcmp() doesn't change the list, it is just the correct way top compare strings in C.

Answer (score 1):

Donot use `temp->name == input`,
use `strcmp(temp->name, input)`
see [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)