# How to compare with If the value of two strings?

Tags: c

I want to compare the two strings and show the amount of wins for each player. I do not quite understand how the string.h library works, but in searches I've shown that it should work for this comparison

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Player 1: ");
    scanf("%s", &play1);
    printf("Player 2: ");
    scanf("%s", &play2);            
    printf("Total matches: ");
    scanf("%d", &t_matches);

    for (i = 1; i <= t_matches; i++) {
        printf("Winner match %d: ", i);
        scanf("%s", &win1);
        if (strcmp(win1, play1)) {
            p1++; 
        } else if(strcmp (win1, play2)) {
            p2++; 
        }
    }
    printf("%s win %d matches\n", play1, p1);
    printf("%s win %d matches\n", play2, p2);
}
```

Comment: `win1`, `play1` and `play2` are not declared anywhere.

Comment: See also [How do I compare strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598425/) and [How to properly compare strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237)

Answer (score 2):

The `strcmp` function returns 0 if the strings are equal.  You're checking if they are unequal.  You instead want:

```
if (strcmp(win1, play1) == 0) {
    p1++; 
} else if(strcmp (win1, play2) == 0) {
    p2++;
}
```