# What does the exclamation point in if (!strcmp() ... do?

Tags: c, operators

Can someone explain what the exclamation point in the if statement does (i.e. `!strmcp`)?

```
 string names[] = {"EMMA", "RODRIGO", "BRIAN", "DAVID"};

// Search for EMMA
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if (!strcmp(names[i], "EMMA"))
    {
        printf("Found\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
printf("Not found\n");
return 1;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using boolean values in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921539/using-boolean-values-in-c)

Comment: The answers to this thread should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598425/how-do-i-check-if-a-value-matches-a-string

Comment: if returns 0, aka false, when the 2 strings match, aka are identical. The ! does a logical not of that false, to get true, and enter the if when the strings are identical. Which is really when found should be printed

Comment: The code is fine, but unclear. Better would be `if (0 == strcmp(...`

Comment: See [How do I check if a value matches a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1598429/15168) for relevant information.  The notation `!strcmp(…)` is equivalent to `strcmp(…) == 0` — but less clear, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

`strcmp()` returns 0 if the strings are identical, so you need to negate it, if you use it in an `if` clause to assert a `true` statement.

If your clause is `if(0)`, the code inside the condition will not be executed.

For completion, it returns negative if the first different character found is lower in the first string, for instance:

**first parameter string: "abca"**

**second parameter string :abcd"**

This will return negative. If it's the other way arround it will return positive.

Also, `string` is not usually used in C (I refer you to Jonathan Leffler's commment), you can use `char*`:

```
char *names[] = {"EMMA", "RODRIGO", "BRIAN", "DAVID"};
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked

Comment: You'd find `string` used in the CS50 course (SO tag [tag:cs50]; SE site [CS50](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/)) — as a synonym (typedef) of `char *`.  I'm not convinced it is a good choice, but that is certainly one place where it is used.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, never heard of it, I'll be sure to add it to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For an if statement, if the expression evaluates to 0, then the block of code following the if statement is not executed. Any other value (positive or negative), will result in executing the code block. The function strcmp uses 0 to say that strings are equal because less than 0 is used to differ from greater than 0.

So in this code, we want `printf("Found\n");` to be executed when the strings are equal. Since strcmp results in 0, we need to negate the value so that it becomes 1 which will result in executing that code block.

Answer (score 1):

Unary operator `!` is called the logical NOT operator (cf., for example, [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical) definition at cppreference.com). `! expression` returns `1` if `expression` evaluates to `0`, and it returns `0` if `expression` evaluates to anything else but `0`.

So the condition in `if (!0)` gives `1`; this means, the condition is met and the if-block is entered. It has the same meaning as `if(0==0)`

Consequently, the meaning of

```
if(!strcmp(names[i], "EMMA"))
```

in your code is exactly the same as

```
if(0==strcmp(names[i], "EMMA"))
```

And you already know when `strcmp` returns `0`...

Answer (score 1):

The exclamation point is the C's boolean negation character. 
It means give me the *boolean* opposite of the value. A boolean is either  `true` or `false`, which are `1` or `0` in the C Language.

In C, `if` statements execute their conditional statements if the argument is true.

`if (a)`   means if `a` is true (i.e. non-zero)
`if (!a)` means if `a` is false (i.e.  0)

Therefore:

`if (a)`   is the same as  `if (a != 0)` 
 `if (!a)` is the same as  `if (a == 0)`

*Sometimes* you'll see code that uses *two* exclamation points in a row "`!!`"

For example:

```
int a = !!b;
```

That ensures `a` will be ONLY `0` or `1`, regardless of what the value of `b` is.

If `b` is ANY non-zero value, the `!` operator will treat it as though it is true `true`, which it treats as being the same as `1`

So:

```
!0 == 1
!1 == 0
!52 == 0
!25692 == 0
```

The second `!` does the boolean inversion again, so:

```
!!0 == 0
!!1 == 1
!!52 == 1
!!25692 == 1
```

Answer (score -1):

In `C` any non zero value is considered ad the logical truth, zero i considered as logical false. `!` is a logical negation. So `!0` (not false) will be the truth and  `if(!strcmp(str1,str2)) {statements}` *statements* will be executed when `str1` will be same as `str2`

Comment: Silent DV-ter explain