# use of strcmp in code, compile->test->fails, debug, realize I forgot 0==strcmp

Tags: c++, c, string

I just have some kind of fundamental perception problem with strcmp, stricmp, compare, etc. I KNOW what they do and I know WHY they do it, but when I'm checking equality I just naturally write "if ( strcmp() )..."  It's backwards logic to me and it just doesn't occur to me (until later when my code block doesn't work) to write "if ( 0==strcmp() )...".  I do this all the time and it slows down my development.  Anyone got a tip to reverse my brain on this?

It's like I needed the function to be named "strdoesntcmp"... (yes I know that it couldn't be used for less- or greater-than that way...).  Sure I could use #define or inline to make such a thing but that's a hack... I just want to reverse my natural thinking on it if that makes sense...

Comment: So you want someone to hack into your mind and change the way you think ? Bwong!

Comment: lol i was just about to post that hahaha

Comment: Don't write `(0 == whatever)`. It's unintuitive; write the other way around and perhaps you'll remember it better. ("If difference is zero").

Comment: Well you've got it tagged C++, so I would say use the C++ string facilities...but seriously, pick a language. They're not the same.

Comment: @cnicutar: yes!  or least a new way of looking at it

Comment: @GmanNickG std::string::compare is the same

Comment: @mark but you would usually use the `==` operator with std::string

Comment: I would suggest this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595450/why-does-strcmp-return-0-when-its-inputs-are-equal

Comment: @eq-, this is a suggested way to write equality comparisons.  The reasoning is that (0 = x) will not compile, (x = 0) may compile and be a bug.

Comment: @eq-, I don't see how "If difference is zero" and "If zero is difference" is different.  Probably a personal preference since they are equivalent, and my personal preference is to write the constant on the left.  I don't necessarily think there is anything misguided about it, especially since there is one class of bugs that this practice can help avoid?

Comment: regarding if (0=x) versus (x=0) i tend to agree with eq- although compilers are pretty good these days about throwing up warnings if you don't do ((x=0))... but for me in this string compare case, putting the ==0 at the end makes my perception problem even that much worse because now i've got to eye-scan to the end of the code line to know the logic direction

Comment: Just keep in mind that `strcmp` means *comparison*, not *equality*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just think, that comparison is, in fact, subbtraction (the microprocessor instructions are also working in such way). So `strcmp` might be called `strsub`, and in such way zero means that the strings are equal.

Or implement the `strcmp` specification on your own. While you work it out, the return values will glue to your mind like `1x1`.

You can think also, that once you have posted to stackOverflow that you are always forgetting `(0==strcmp)` and got a lot of confusing answers to it. Once you have this remembered, your mind could not mistake anymore that the `compare` operator is not the `equality` operator.

Comment: i like the "subtraction" or "difference" analogy...

Comment: first of all, thanks for answering the question i asked, which was "i need another way of looking at it."  after sleeping on this, i think this will work for me... every time i use the strxxx functions, i'm going to think "strdiff"... i.e. if the "difference" is zero, they're the same.  i may go so far as to create a strdiff inline, but probably won't use it since it'll be unintuitive to others viewing/editing my code.  thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The best answer is to forget `strcmp` entirely.

```
std::string s1 = "one";
std::string s2 = "two";
if (s1 == s2) // ...
```

Edit: If you were familiar with assembly the `strcmp` function wouldn't confuse you at all. Many processors have a `CMP` instruction that do a subtraction of two values without storing the result, it just sets the condition flags that tell you if the result was negative, zero, or positive. `strcmp` just simulates the same thing with strings.

Comment: i did start using that convention for std::strings at one point, but it doesn't work in const char * situations of course, and also there's the lack of stricmp and strncmp ability which hindered my "acceptance" of it as my main convention...

Comment: @mark: " but it doesn't work in const char * situations of course" Says who? `if (s1 == "three")`? Sounds like you need to discover [Boost](http://www.boost.org/). It'll get lots of boiler-plate out of the way.

Comment: @mark - you can override the char_traits in basic_string, which std::string is an instantiation of, and get case insensitivity.  Alternatively you can call the old C functions on the return of c_str().

Comment: i'm not starting a project from scratch, i'm in a large project with mixed use of C/C++ strings... throwing Boost into it, not a chance.  and i can't use std:string (without paying the penalty of creating one) when both strings are const char *... at least one would need to be in that example, and that's also assuming we're not comparing case-insensitive or to n-chars.  anyway, like i said, i'm looking for a mind-reset of some kind...

Comment: @mark, you can always construct one of the strings on the fly: `if (std::string("one") == "two")`. And I haven't seen any suggestions for boost, I don't know why you bring it up.

Answer (score 4):

```
int streq( char const* s1, char const* s2)
{
    return 0 == strcmp(s1, s2);
}
```

`inline` it if the performance overhead bothers you.

Comment: He wants to learn "the way", not to invent a workaround. :)

Comment: External identifiers beginning with `str` are reserved for future use, so one should perhaps consider using an alternative name for this helper function.

Comment: @eq- that's interesting about strxxx being reserved...

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not as intuitive as you want it to be is because you want to use this to compare the strings == or !=. That's not the whole point of the strcmp function. The point is it can return `str1 > str2`, `str1 == str2`, or `str1 < str2` and you can use those different returns for different reasons.

If you REALLY can't keep them straight in your head, and you **only** use this function to make == or != type compairions you can always reverse it for yourself:

```
#define strcmp !strcmp
```

Then it works they way you want it to, but as I mentioned, you're losing functionality by doing this.

Comment: You're also going to lose your sanity by doing this. :o

Comment: I would rather make my own function that wraps it. Looking down, I guess that's been suggested :p

Comment: buyer beware. :) I never said it was a **good** idea, just that it will make it "work" as the OP wanted.

Comment: No; it would perhaps fix a single erroneus condition, but could easily break existing code even in OP's case (as he hinted he's possibly using `strcasecmp` also; he could very well use function pointers to them, too)

Comment: indeed, disaster would unfold...