# Checking if a string exists in an array only returns true for 1 of the valid strings in C

Tags: arrays, c, function

Say that I have an array that holds the names of various items for purchase at a fast food place...

```
char options[8][15] = {"burger", "fries", "pop", "apples", "vegan burger", "vegan fries"};
```

and an uninitialized variable that will hold the customer's order...

```
char choice[15];
```

I am using a function `exists_in_array()` to iterate through the options array and check if the choice variable matches any of the strings contained inside the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

...

int exists_in_array(char value[], char (array) [8][15])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(value, array[i]) == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

...

int main(void)
{
    char options[8][15] = {"burger", "fries", "pop", "apples", "vegan burger", "vegan fries"};
    char choice[15];

    printf("Enter your choice: ");
    fgets(choice, 15, stdin);
    strtok(choice, "\n");    // Removing the trailing newline that gets recorded with fgets

    if (exists_in_array(choice, options))
    {
        printf("That is a valid option");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("That is not a valid option");
    }
}
```

I am not getting any error messages at the moment, but the only option that will ever return `That is a valid option` is `burger`. Every other item will say `That is not a valid option` and I can't figure out why this is happening. It can't be the newline character that gets added with `fgets()` because I use `strtok()` to remove it immediately afterwards.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: Not sure what documentation you're looking at but `strcmp` doesn't return true/false.

Comment: It returns a 1 or 0 right? true or false are placeholders for 1 and 0 from the `stdbool.h` header file that I included to help readability.

Comment: No, it returns negative, zero, or positive values. While true/false might also have values 1/0, I don't think you should use them. The interface is not "returns true/false as defined in stdbool.h".

Comment: You really should read the documentation instead of guessing. Especially when there is a conflict between your guess and a feedback here...

Comment: ah ok I will do that

Comment: Change `strcmp(value, array[i]) == true` to `strcmp(value, array[i]) == 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation for `strcmp()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html):

> `strcmp()` returns an integer indicating the result of the comparison, as follows:
>
> - 0, if the strings `s1` and `s2` are equal;
> - a negative value if `s1` is less than `s2`;
> - a positive value if `s1` is greater than `s2`.

Your check should be:

```
if (!strcmp(value, array[i])) { // ...
// Or, more explicitly:
if (strcmp(value, array[i]) == 0) { // ...
```

Comment: Ok thanks I will try that. This seems like a really counter-intuitive way to design the function in my opinion, but I guess there are reasons for having it this way.

Comment: Well counter intuitive or not, that depends, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595450/why-does-strcmp-return-0-when-its-inputs-are-equal

Comment: Ah ok I see. That makes more sense thank you! Just coming from the perspective of a newcomer to the language, that's not the way that one might expect it to work without having it explained to them.

Answer (score 0):

```
int exists_in_array(const char *value, char **options)
{
    while(options && *options)
    {
        if(!strcmp(value, *options))
        {
            return true;
        }
        options++;
    }
    return false;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *options[] = {"burger", "fries", "pop", "apples", "vegan burger", "vegan fries", NULL};
    char choice[15];

    printf("Enter your choice: ");
    fgets(choice, 15, stdin);
    if(*choice) choice[strlen(choice)] = 0; 

    if (exists_in_array(choice, options))
    {
        printf("That is a valid option");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("That is not a valid option");
    }
}
```