# Why is strlen() not returning correct value?

Tags: arrays, c, string, libraries

Hi I am sorry that this is sort of a repeat, but none of the other solutions have been able to help me. The variables found and tofind are both `"Point"` but when I call the `strcmp` I get a negative number and when I print their lengths found has a len of 9. Can someone please help me understand why that is and how to fix(how to make found and tofind have the same values and lengths)? Thank you so much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) {
  char found[] = "";
  char tofind[] = "Point";


  int i = 0;

  while(i < 5){
    char f = tofind[i];


    strcat(found, &f);
    i++;

  }

  int r = strcmp(found, tofind);
  printf("%d\n", r);

  printf("Found: %s with len: %lu\n", found, strlen(found));//says len is 9

  printf("To Find: %s with len: %lu", tofind, strlen(tofind)); //says len is 5

return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
./main
-104
Found: Point with len: 9 this is i: 5
To Find: Point with len: 5
```

Comment: @ay This call strcat(found, &f); does not make a sense. The array found has only one element.

Comment: `strcat(found, &f);` this line

Comment: `strcat(found, &f);` invokes *undefined behavior* because it will cause out-of-range access by both read (passing something not null-terminated) and write (connecting to 1-element array).

Comment: `&f` is not a string; connot use it in `strcat()`.

Comment: @Blindy Why do you have decided that it is a read-only section?!

Comment: Dupe: [Why does strcmp() return 0 when its inputs are equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595450/why-does-strcmp-return-0-when-its-inputs-are-equal)